# unable to perform debootstrap in docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to use `debootstrap` in a docker container to build a minimal ubuntu image.

This is the command that i've been executing in the terminal to run the docker container.

```
curDir=$(pwd)
mkdir -p "$curDir"/workspace
docker run \
   --volume /host_mnt/"$curDir"/workspace:/home/workspace \
   --platform linux/amd64 \
   --privileged \
   --cap-add=ALL \
   -it \
   ubuntu /bin/bash
```

however, when i try to do: `debootstrap --arch arm64 --foreign jammy /home/workspace/` it results in the below error:

```
mknod: /home/workspace/test-dev-null: Operation not permitted
E: Cannot install into target '/home/workspace' mounted with noexec or node
```

i've been trying to search for different ways to `mount` the host computer's directory (my computer) into docker with `exec,dev` permissions, but i'm not able to find out how this should be properly done.

Also, I understand it's not a good idea to give `--privileged` and `ALL` in `cap-add` , so any advice here will be great!